# What was Tyrion proposing when he asked Daenerys to consider the succession?

Tags: game-of-thrones

There's a scene in the most recent season of GoT where Tyrion brings up the issue of succession to Daenarys. He reminds her that she's likely infertile and goes on to suggest she *do something* about a successor naming two examples: "The night's watch have one method. The ironborn [...] have another".

These particular examples are notable because they're both (sort of) democracies. They have a form of election to select their next leaders, but more peculiarly they hold elections specifically in the event of the current ruler's death. In the real world, this just isn't done; not even in democracies. A pre-existing well-defined line-of-succession is a critical deterrent against assassination. One would think Tyrion who is presented as a political genius would understand at least this much.

So what exactly *is* he proposing she do about succession?

Comment: Come up with a way to make sure her line (and ideals carries on). Whether that is creating an election process, her picking someone to carry on, trying for a baby (even if she thinks she;s infertile).

Comment: Interestingly Tyrion gets first-hand experience of true democracy amongst the hill tribes of the Vale in the books. At the time he's not very impressed, but it's possible both books and TV are going down the route of Tyrion suggesting democracy as an alternative to monarchy (and it definitely fits with Daenarys' "break the wheel" speech).

Comment: @delinear Well technically he's already suggested democracy, albeit in an indirect wya.

Comment: The critical point of my post was less about holding elections and more about _when_ they're held (namely, _in the event of death_). In the opening chapter of "Storm of Swords" we see just how disastrous this policy is. The POV character is about to assassinate Lord Commander Mormont specifically because he knows that in the resulting chaos no one's going to bother to come looking for him.

Comment: Is Tyrion suggesting they hold elections for her successor right now? Who would vote in them? What if the result isn't someone she trusts?

Comment: @dspyz 1) He didn't suggest anything directly. 2) No suggestions made so who knows. 3) Again with no suggestions we can't know. Dany cut him off before anything further could be said so we don't know what his suggestion truly was.

Answer (score 5):

The complete conversation is as follows and as is evidenced Tyrion is mainly worried about carrying on the succession he isn't proposing anything yet. He implies that a democratic solution could be an answer by suggesting the Night's Watch's elections and the Ironborns Kings Moot but get's cut off before he can complete the sentence. Tyrion hasn't actually suggested anything he is just worried about the succession continuing and even if he has a suggestion Dany wouldn't hear it.

> **Tyrion Lannister**: Because I believe in you and the world you want to build. But the world you want to build doesn't get built all at once. Probably not in a single lifetime. How do we ensure your vision endures? After you break the wheel, how do we make sure it stays broken?
>
> **Daenerys Targaryen**: You want to know who sits on the Iron Throne after I'm dead?
>
> **Tyrion Lannister**: You say you can't have children. But there are other ways of choosing a successor. The Night's Watch has one method, The Iron born folk, although many flaws
>
> **Daenerys Targaryen**: We will discuss the succession after I wear the crown.
>
> **Tyrion Lannister**: Your Grace, I saw hundreds of arrows fly towards you when you fought on Blackwater Rush, and I saw hundred of arrows miss. But any one of them could have found your heart and ended you.
>
> **Daenerys Targaryen**: You've been thinking about my death quite a bit, haven't you? Is this one of the items you've discussed with your brother in King's Landing?
>
> **Tyrion Lannister**: I'm trying to serve you by planning for the long term.
>
> **Daenerys Targaryen**: Perhaps if you'd planned for the short term, we wouldn't have lost Dorne and Highgarden. We will discuss the succession after I wear the crown.
>
> <sup>Game of Thrones, Season 7 Episode 6, "Beyond the Wall"</sup>

However, the ending to Season 7 could have put Tyrion's mind at rest when he saw the potential for **#BOATBABY**. Though of course he seems to look more worried than happy about the situation.

[image: Tyrion see's Jon entering Dany's cabin]

An important point mentioned by [@Anthony Grist in the comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185039/what-was-tyrion-proposing-when-he-asked-daenerys-to-consider-the-succession/185040?noredirect=1#comment502171_185040) is also relvant here. Just because he wanted to discuss the matter and start thinking about it right now doesn't mean he wants anything to happen straight away. For all we know Tyrion has no idea for what should happen with the succession but just wanted to open the discussion up so there was a possibility there.

Comment: Sure, but if he wants to discuss the matter _now_, then presumably that means he wants her to do something about it _now_; _before_ she "wears the crown". And I just can't imagine what he thinks she should do at this very moment (given the examples he chose).

Comment: @dspyz Well we don't know because she wouldn't discuss it.

Comment: @dspyz That's a leap. Wanting her to start thinking about it now does **not** mean he wants her to immediately take action.

Comment: I find it odd because to me it seems critical that she _should_ choose a successor *right now* _before_ she wears the crown. This is an important thing for any leader to do (if only as a deterrent as I mentioned before; consider what happened to Renly Baratheon because he failed to name a successor) and Tyrion is absolutely right to bring it up. But he seems to be confusing the matter by talking about democracy, which is certainly _not_ important or relevant at the moment, and seems generally counter-productive.

Comment: @dspyz She can't have children (or think she can't) so he's bringing up a democracy as an alternative. As for if it's critical or not that depends on your viewpoint. Tyrion thinks her vision is more important and should be maintained no matter the outcome. Dany thinks her vision doesn't matter at the moment until the war is won. Why pick a successor if you're only going to lose?

Comment: Picking a successor can make the difference between winning and losing. Had Renly named a successor, Stannis probably wouldn't have bothered to go South and assassinate him. That was primarily a strategic move knowing that all his armies would come over to his side because there's no one else to follow. Renly might have sat the iron throne. That's how deterrents work. They can help you in the present too.

Comment: @dspyz I think that's a big leap to assume that. Also Renly's armies did not go over to Stannis' side.

Comment: I thought a lot of them did (although critically, not High Garden which was most of it). In any case, it's clear that's what Stannis expected to happen which is kind of the point. Renly didn't make it clear what would happen in the event of his death and Stannis tried to exploit that (and his natural claim as the brother) by killing him.

Comment: @dspyz This is tangential to the question at hand anyway. If you would like to talk general ASOIAF/GoT you're welcome to join us in [The Quill and Tankard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39179/the-quill-and-tankard).

Comment: Perhaps Tyrion is thinking about himself instead.  Should Dany be killed before Tyrion's demise, without a successor, all her followers would be subject to the conqueror.  If that were Cersei, she would punish Tyrion severely.  If a successor were at least named, Tyrion would be able to maintain his position, provided that Dany is already ruler and not just a rebel.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths That is of course a theory but I'm not entirely sure that's his game plan there

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot My point is, we don't know what he really was after and it could be anything at this point.  We'll all have to wait until the long winter (wait) is over.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Which is exactly what I say in my answer.